# PostgreSQL partitioned table and partitions in different schemas

Tags: postgresql, ddl, database-partitioning

I'm planning to partition a huge table in postgresql. I'm using pgsql-13.

I'm evaluating the possibility to create the master table in schema "**public**" and the partitions in a new different schema (schema "**parts**").

I have tested the idea and it works fine. Even with all of its triggers and everything.

The question is: will this cause any performance issues or something?

I couldn't really find much about it in the web or the docs.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No problem at all, a schema is just a namespace. All tables are registered in pg_class, no matter what schema they use. I do it all the time, for clarity.

Comment: Got it, that makes sense. Indeed, the purpose is to keep it all clean and clear. Thanks for your answer!